# A basic question on expectation of distribution composed random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with distribution functions $F$ and $G$. If $F$ and $G$ have no common jumps then I need to show that $E[F(Y)] + E[G(X)] = 1$.

How to proceed here ? Shall I try to show that the LHS is some probability of almost sure events or product of two almost sure events. Clearly, $F(Y)$ and $G(X)$ are random variables with range in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking to these functions $ F(Y) $ and $G(X)$. Well,

$F(Y(w)) = P(X \le Y(w)) $ and similar $ G(X(w)) = P(Y \le X(w))$ this gives you an idea.

$$ E [G(X) + F(Y)] = \int_{\Omega}P(X \le Y(w)) + P(Y \le X(w)) dP(w)  $$

and this integral you can divide into three parts

$$ \int_{X < Y} P(X \le Y(w)) + P(Y \le X(w)) dP(w) + \int_{Y < X} P(X \le Y(w)) + P(Y \le X(w)) dP(w) + \int_{X = Y} P(X \le Y(w)) + P(Y \le X(w)) dP(w)$$

Note that in the first and second terms $ P(X \le Y(w))+ P(Y \le X(w)) = 1$, so we have

$$\int_{X < Y} P(X \le Y(w)) + P(Y \le X(w)) dP(w) = P(X<Y)$$

$$\int_{Y < X} P(X \le Y(w)) + P(Y \le X(w)) dP(w) = P(X>Y)$$

for the third term the hypothesis tells us that it is zero.

Hope this gives you at least an idea...